# Как построить обработку входящего текста?

Tags: java

Вообщем нужно сделать так: Программа получает на вход текст, ищет в нем части которые начинаются с символа x, и заканчивается символом y (это любой знак закачивающий предложение), и складывает сточку в i. Далее программа берет следующее предложение и складывает его в h. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону **средств считывания входных данных**(Если уровень начальный подойдёт Scanner), форматирование строки можно производить с помощью **регулярных выражений** либо **различных методов Java для работы со строками**.